# An expression to selection within subsets of vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Does anyone have an idea on "an expression to selection within subsets of vector layer in qgis"? Qgis has “Random selection within subset” to select randomly but I have to select within subset with the expression where a condition is:

WHEN case
there are more than one class, then select only one '1', 
if there is no '1' then select '2', 
if there is no '1' & '2' then select a '3'.

a[image: my points layer's attribute]n

Comment: where is your remarks count ?

Comment: #snaileater,  I recently edited the question

Comment: You seem just trying to calculate minimum `class` value for each `subset` group. I would suggest to try `minimum("class", group_by:="subset")`......Probably I am just reading at its face value; I don't know.

Comment: @Kazuhito, I am trying to select only one value per one subset, as shown in the picture; subset 2 has 5 values (3,3,2,1,2) from them I just trying to select the row that has value 1. Do you have an idea about it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the minimum class value for each subset - as Kazuhito decifers - your can also use a Virtuel Layer (of the Datasource Manager) in QGIS:

```
select someothercolums, min(class), subset   
from test
group by subset;
```

Comment: Thank you #Jakob,

WHEN case
if there is class 1&2&3 then select only '1',
if there are class 2&3 then select only '2',
if there is class 3 then select only '3'



And I am trying to select only one value per one subset,

like subset 1 has 10 values (3,3,1,2,1,2,2,3,2) from them I just trying to select the row that has value 1.

Comment: My virtual layer selects the minimum class value of each subset group. Is this not what you want as result?

Comment: How to perform this task #Jakob?  Virtual Layer (of the Datasource Manager) in QGIS:

select someothercolums, min(class), subset   
from test
group by subset;

Comment: In QGIS press Ctrl + L goto Virtual Layer and add the sql code, drop the someothercolumns text....

Comment: #Jakob, Virtual Layer displays the following error; Referenced table test in query not found.

Comment: You have to enter your own tablename.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer for future references.